# Why isn't there a bronze badge for 10 people favoriting a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-request, bookmarks

There are currently two badges for questions favorited by a certain number of users:

> **Favorite Question** Question favorited by 25 users
>   **Stellar Question** Question favorited by 100 users

Why isn't there a bronze badge for a question favorited by 10 users? This would fit with the pattern of Nice/Good/Great badges for questions/answers, which require 10/25/100 votes. Thanks!

Comment: Do we have to have badges for everything?

Comment: @Random: No, but I like consistency... When things aren't consistent, they drive me crazy...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto consistent with what?  There are other things that only have silver/gold badges (Enthusiast/Fanatic, and sort of Civic duty/Electorate).  To be *truly* consistent you'd want to introduce bronze level badges for those too :)

Comment: We used to have one, but it totally dissed Jon Skeet one day, and was from thenceforth banned from the site.  The remainder of the badges have learned to be more respectful as a result.

Comment: @Daniel: Consistant with the Nice/Good/Great question/answer badges.

Comment: @Daniel, I consider that Supporter is the bronze for Civic Duty/Electorate :)

Comment: @random Of course not. But maybe a badge for a question favorited by 10 users is more "worthy" than, say, a badge for one's first rollback ("Cleanup").

Comment: @random Yes!  Now where's my contrarian badge?

Comment: @random - Why... Yes. Yes, we do. To boost self-esteem & such.

Comment: Favouriting a question doesn't mean I like the question. Quite often it's combined with a downvote, to remind me to remove the downvote if the question improves.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

+1 I had thought the exact same question but I never asked :-P

How about

> **Worthy Question** Question favorited by 10 users
>
> **Favorite Question** Question favorited by 25 users
> **Stellar Question** Question favorited by 100 users

Comment: Worthy/Good. Might get a little confusing there.

Comment: @Cole perhaps we could name the badge "Bookmark", or "Clippy" :)

Answer (score 32):

A possible reason for the lack of a bronze "favoriting" badge is that favoriting seems to perform two somewhat different functions:

- Users might want to watch a question closely for a time -- they're interested in possible answers to it, or perhaps plan to write an answer themselves if no one else comes up with a good one. Questions of this kind normally will be removed from a user's "Favorite" selection after a while.
- Users might feel that a question and/or some of its existing answers are of special interest to them, sort of "canonical". Although the user's interest might wear away eventually, the inital intention at least is to add such questions to one's "Favorite" list for good.

I suppose that the existing "Favorite Question" and "Stellar Question" silver/gold badges only aim at favorites of the second type. And with 25 or even 100 "Favorite" marks, a question surely is of the "canonical" kind. Perhaps the SO developers felt that with 10 marks, one can't be sure if a question is only of passing interest to its followers, and therefore they didn't introduce a corresponding bronze badge. To find out whether the developers were right, one would have to delve into SO's data dump.

(Some evidence from tex.sx, mostly anecdotic: Ar the moment, 28 "Favorite Question" badges and zero "Stellar Question" badges have been earned [a few questions are close to "Stellar"]. The number of questions with at least 10 "Favorite" marks seems to be about five to ten times lower than the number of questions with a "Nice Question" badge, i.e., the former questions are probably of permanent interest to their followers. For tex.sx, I'd say: Yes, please introduce a "Worthy Question" bronze badge!)

EDIT: According to the latest data dump, the frequency of the proposed "Worthy Question" badge would be somewhat above that of the "Good Question" badge at SO. At tex.sx., "Worthy Questions" would be even rarer than "Good Questions".

```
                                SO   tex.sx

Stellar Questions              419        0
Favorite Questions           3,694       28
Questions with >= 10        14,913      147
    "Favorite" marks
    ("Worthy Questions")

Great Questions*               986        3
Good Questions*             10,357      162
Nice Questions*             51,090    1,762

* as of 2012-02-05
```

EDIT: Another possible concern with regard to the suggested "Worthy Question" badge is that users [are allowed to favorite their own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/mark-my-own-question-as-favorite), and so may chip in 10% of the "Worthy Question" requirement. I don't think this tips the scale against the proposed badge. (And if it's really a concern, the criteria for the [Worthy/]Favorite/Stellar Question badges could be changed to "Question favorited by 10/25/100 *other* users.)

Disclosure: If a "Worthy Question" badge would be introduced and retroactively applied to existing questions, I'd earn this badge five times at tex.sx.

Comment: Even getting 10 people to watch a question for a time is worthy of something, I would think...