# "Interesting question" badge

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Shouldn't there be an [Interesting Question http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Interesting%20Question&c=b](http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Interesting%20Question&c=b) badge for questions marked favorite by 10 users?

By analogy with question score:

- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Nice%20Question&c=b Question score of 10 or more
- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Good%20Question&c=s Question score of 25 or more
- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Great%20Question&c=g Question  Question score of 100 or more

Question marked favorite:

- **http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Interesting%20Question&c=b Question favorited by 10 users or more**
- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Favorite%20Question&c=s Question favorited by 25 users **or more**
- http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Stellar%20Question&c=g Question  Question favorited by 100 users **or more**

[SO Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92962/why-isnt-there-a-bronze-badge-for-10-people-favoriting-a-question?rq=1